# Получение количества и списка полей таблицы

Tags: access, python, база-данных, запрос, sql

Какой sql запрос получает количество полей таблицы Access в pyodbc соединении с базой?
Какой sql запрос получает список полей таблицы Access в pyodbc соединении с базой?

Comment: может поможет - копайте в сторону "метаданных". Это и есть данные о структуре БД

Comment: [Select column names in a table using PyODBC][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227836/

Answer (score 1):

У курсора из модуля `pyodbc` есть метод `columns(table_name)`, который выдает исчерпывающую информацию по колонкам таблицы. Так же есть метод `tables(mask=None)`, который дает инфу по таблицам.